# Poker dice game, and I don't know why my methods have errors on them

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);   
    int[] dice = new int[5];
    resetDice(dice);
    System.out.print("Your current dice: + dice");
    rollDice(dice);
    System.out.print(dice);
    System.out.println();
    promptForReroll(dice, inScanner);
    System.out.println("Rerolling...");
    rollDice(dice);
    System.out.println("Your final dice: + dice");
    System.out.println(getResult(dice)+"!");      
}

private static void resetDice(int[] dice) {
    int length = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        dice[i] = 0;
    }
}

private static void rollDice(int[] dice) {
    int i = 0;
    int length = 5;

    while(i < length) {
        if(dice[i] == 0) {
            int roll = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
            dice[i] = roll;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

private static String diceToString(int[] dice) {
    String diceToString =("Your current dice: " +dice[0]+", " +dice[1]+ ", " +dice[2]+ ", " +dice[3]+ ", " +dice[4]);
    return diceToString;    
}

private static void promptForReroll(int[] dice, Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.print("Select a die to re-roll (-1 to keep remaining dice): ");
    int selection = inScanner.nextInt();
    while(selection != -1){
        if(selection > 4 || selection < -1){
            System.out.println("Erorr: Index must be between 0 and 4 (-1 to quit)!");
        }
        else{
            dice[selection] = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Your current dice: " + dice);
        System.out.print("Select a die to re-roll (-1 to keep remaining dice): ");
        selection = inScanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Keeping remaining die...");
}

private static boolean promptForPlayAgain(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(Y or N)");
    String play = inScanner.nextLine();
    if(play=="Y"){
        return true;
    }
    else if(play=="N"){
        return false;
    }
}

private static String getResult(int[] dice) {
    getCounts(dice);
}

private static int[] getCounts(int[] dice) {
    int[] count = new int[6];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i<5){
        while(j<5){
            if(dice[i] == (j+1)){
                count[j]++;
                i++;
            }       
            else{
                i++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I have written out the coding, and I think for the most part it may be right, but I can't run it because it has errors on my `promptForPlayAgain` method, and my `getResult` method. I don't know why there are errors on them.

Comment: You should at least tell us what the errors are.

Comment: For my getResult method, it says "This method must return a result of type String"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything if the user's input isn't `"Y"` or `"N"`. You need to add an `else` case:

```
private static Boolean promptForPlayAgain(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(Y or N)");
    String play = inScanner.nextLine();
    if(play=="Y"){
        return true;
    }
    else if(play=="N"){
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something here to handle bad input. 
    }
}
```

Ideally though, you should be doing some kind of formatting and preverification of the input, like forcing the input to upper case before comparing.

And on `getResult`, you aren't returning anything. Add a `return` before the body of the function. That won't fix it though, since the return type of `getValue` doesn't match `getResult`. You're trying to return a int array as a string.

In the future, please include the actual error messages they you receive.

Comment: For promptForPlayAgain, what do i need to add? and on my getResult method what do i need to return?

Comment: @osubucs28 For both, that's up to you. For the first, you need to decide how you'll handle bad input; you can't assume the user will always enter the correct input. The easiest way would to  ask for input from the user inside of a loop, and only exit the loop once you've validated the input. For `getResult`, I can't say since I don't understand what your intent is. What are you trying to accomplish with `getResult`? Should it return a String or an int array?

Comment: The method should evaluate the array and return back to the calling program a String containing the score from the array of dice. This is what i need the getResult method to do.

Comment: @osubucs28 But in your original code, `getValue` is returning an int array, but then you never use it. If you want to use the result of `getValue`, you'll need to actually return it, ad format the array into a string. Unless the string is solely for visual purposes, it's likely not the best way to pass information, as you'll need to parse it again later.

Comment: so do i even need the getResult method?

Comment: If you don't care how pretty the output is, you could just call `toString` on the array. Otherwise, you could use the method to pretty up the array. Formatting collections for output is a common requirement, and is a separate problem. It's worth practicing it's so common.

Comment: The output needs to look like this:                                                                    Your current dice: 4 2 1 4 6 
Select a die to re-roll (-1 to keep remaining dice): 1
Your current dice: 4 0 1 4 6 
Select a die to re-roll (-1 to keep remaining dice): 2
Your current dice: 4 0 0 4 6 
Select a die to re-roll (-1 to keep remaining dice): 4
Your current dice: 4 0 0 4 0 
Select a die to re-roll (-1 to keep remaining dice): -1
Keeping remaining dice...
Rerolling...
Your final dice: 4 2 3 4 6 
One pair!
Would you like to play again [Y/N]?: y

Comment: In the coding you provided above, what do i need to add under the last else.

Comment: Either throw a exception indicating bad input that's caught elsewhere, or reconfigure it to loop while the input is bad.

Comment: I recommend temporarily putting this project aside and practicing taking user input and formatting output. You also shouldn't be outputting to the console directly from the method in most scenarios. This is getting very offtopic though. Try to work it out and post another *specific* question when you run into a problem. Also be sure to include *exactly* what errors/problems you get. The community shouldn't have to guess what you're problems are.